# Plotting custom error bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, standard-error, errorbar

I have this code for a barplot in R

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Drugs, aes(factor(Drug), Avbpm, fill = Rate)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
   ylab("Beats Per Minute") + xlab("Drug") +  
   theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 350, 25), limits = c(0, 330))
```

Where this is my data

```
Drugs <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='Rate        Drug  Bpm1 Bpm2 Bpm3
1   "Basal Heart Rate"               Nicotine     188 154 158
2   "Drug Induced Heart Rate"       Nicotine      274 250 246
3   "Basal Heart Rate"        Acetylcholine      200 246 216
4   "Drug Induced Heart Rate"  Acetylcholine      96 218 208
5   "Basal Heart Rate"           Atropine       220 120 440
6   "Drug Induced Heart Rate"      Atropine       280 156 540
7   "Basal Heart Rate"            Lidocaine      200 360 320
8   "Drug Induced Heart Rate"        Lidocaine     168 240 236')

library(dplyr)
Drugs <- Drugs %>%
  mutate(Avbpm = select(., starts_with("B")) %>%
                             rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which is a total of 8 bars,I want to add error bars to each for each given standard error of the mean for example the Basal HR for nicotine would have error bars of 10.72898
However I'm not sure how to do this-- Thanks!

Comment: `Error in factor(Reason) : object 'Reason' not found`

Comment: There are so many ggplot error bar questions that's actually hard to pick one to flag.

Comment: Sorry posted the wrong ggplot function at first!! -- just fixed it

Comment: @harre sorry posted the wrong function at first